# Returning ModelAndView does not work with user-defined functions

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Returning ModelAndView object not working with user-defined function Here is my Code

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/welcome",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView hello(){
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index");
        model.addObject("msg", "checking ModelAndView return!!!");
        return model;
    }

}
```

Comment: what is user-defined function here ? And not working means what? Voting to close. Put some effort into this question

Comment: hello() is the user-defined function; not working means http 404 error is coming if i use public String hello(){ return "index";} its working but if i return model its not working

Comment: PWC6117: File "null" not found in my server log

Comment: public class HelloController implements Controller {
 
    @Override
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
            ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index");
            model.addObject("msg", "Spring MVC without annotation by implementing Controller interface!!!");
            return model;
    }
} is working perfectly whereas the above one is not

Comment: i do have an index.jsp file in the web-inf folder still i get file "null" not found please help

Answer (score 0):

instead of using import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

i have used import org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView;
that was the problem